# Chrome is not rendering div, but MS Edge and development build is rendering as intended using React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, react-bootstrap

The site is live at http://www.ipworld.ca/
but it should look like this:
[from dev build viewed using chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpTeB.jpg)
I tried increasing the z-order through css, but no luck. Notice the elements are loaded, but are not shown in the live version.

Comment: Setting a `z-index` on an element has no effect on the element unless it is a positioned element. Try adding `position: relative` to the component and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the transparency of the card. 
Just make these changes in css.

```
.services-card {
    max-width: 66%;
    opacity: 1; 
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

The opacity will affect the visibility of the all the contents in the div. 
In your case, you should change the background.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp

Comment: Perfect, that worked like a charm. Never would have figured out I should have set opacity though bg instead.